# How to place an artifact in a remote server and unzip

Tags: jenkins, gradle, nexus, continuous-deployment

Hi have requirement to Continous deployment using Jenkins and below are the steps to achieve.
1.Jenkins job download the artifact from Nexus and place it in a remote server
2.Unzip the artifact present in the remote server.
3.Perform Gradle task in remote server

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Ansible maybe https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/copy_module.html

If it is Windows:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/win_unzip_module.html

You have modules for every situation:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/modules_by_category.html

You could do it with Jenkins, scripting the code, and probably storing the login in the Jenkins credentials.

Comment: My jenkins running on windows platform and i think ansible won't work in windows.Is there any alternate way to achieve this

Comment: Chef runs well in Windows, I have used it in the past successfully. https://docs.chef.io/windows/